# How many processes are created in this excerpt of code?

Tags: c, process, fork

Can you help me with this? I'm a little bit confused with the creation of processes, i think the number of processes created are 7, am i right?

```
int main(){
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pid = fork();
        if(pid > 0){
            printf("I'm father\n");
        }else{
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why would you think it's 7?  hint `man fork`

Comment: @KevinDTimm why wouldn't he think it's 7, given that it's the correct answer? :)

Comment: My thought was that it was 4: the parent (the non-zero return for each iteration) and the 3 children, one created on each iteration of the loop. However, looking @ John's answer below I see I may need to update my thinking.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, 7 processes are forked (plus there's the original parent process, for a grand total of 8).  The key concept is that forked processes are initially (near-)exact duplicates of their parents, so in particular, they have the same variable values, and start executing by returning from the `fork()` call.  This table maps out the forks that will occur in your program:

```
  i  proc0  proc1  proc2  proc3  proc4  proc5  proc6  proc7
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  0    +1    new
  1    +1     +1    new    new
  2    +1     +1     +1     +1    new    new    new    new
```

The `+1`s indicate forks; add them up to get 7.  Forked processes 4 - 7 are created when `i == 2`, but do not themselves fork because they fall out the bottom of the loop before they can do so (and their parents fall out the bottom before they can fork again).

Note, too, that the labels of processes `proc2` - `proc7` do not directly convey information about parentage or creation order; the table merely associates each label with the value of variable `i` when it is forked, and depicts how many times each process forks as a function of its value of `i` when it starts running.

Comment: that was my reasoning but i was not sure of that, thank you so much :)

Comment: @jschultz410, Process "child3" is one of two forked by a parent having `i == 1` at the time of the fork (see the first column of the table); it may be either a direct child of the original process or its grandchild.  Since it is forked with `i == 1`, it certainly will perform one iteration of the loop, during which it will fork.  It is one of four processes that will call `fork()` while having `i == 2`.

Comment: @jschultz410, I chose the column labelling I did, and the "+1", to avoid incorrect implications about the order of events (which even so I do not completely achieve).  To address the potential confusion, therefore, I have added columns to the table for the other four processes.  I hope that having labels child4 - child7 on the table, as opposed to only in the text, will increase the likelihood that readers will recognize that these refer to all the subprocesses, regardless of parent.

Comment: @jschultz410, ok, I relabeled the processes to avoid "child" terminology.  My original thought was not to trace ancestry, but merely to distinguish the forked processes from the original process.  This distinction is de-emphasized by the new labeling, but not altogether lost, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to see what's going on if you print a message from the child when the child is created.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void )
{
    pid_t pid;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid > 0)
            sleep(1);       // give the child time to print its message
        else if (pid == 0)
            printf( "I'm child %d, my parent is %d\n", getpid(), getppid() );
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
I'm child 308, my parent is 307
I'm child 309, my parent is 308
I'm child 310, my parent is 309
I'm child 312, my parent is 308
I'm child 311, my parent is 307
I'm child 313, my parent is 311
I'm child 314, my parent is 307
```